# Select same column twice + JOIN

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a system where a user can report another user.

I want to get the following data

report id | report motive | report owner_id | report owner username | reported user id | reported user username | creation date

Reports

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id INTEGER REFERENCES Registered(user_id),
creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
motive VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'TOA Violation' NOT NULL
active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
```

Reporteduser

```
report_id INTEGER REFERENCES Report(id),
user_id INTEGER REFERENCES Registered(user_id),
PRIMARY KEY(report_id, user_id)
```

Person

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

I wrote

```
SELECT DISTINCT report.id, report.owner_id AS source_id, reporteduser.user_id AS target_id, report.motive, report.creation_date,
(SELECT person.username
 FROM person
 JOIN reporteduser
 ON person.id = reporteduser.user_id) AS target_user,
(SELECT person.username
 FROM person
 JOIN report
 ON person.id = report.owner_id) AS source_user
FROM report
JOIN person
ON report.owner_id = person.id
JOIN reporteduser
ON reporteduser.report_id = report.id
WHERE report.active = TRUE;
```

The problem being that the subqueries give me all the users at once. It does work wonders with only one report.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need all those subqueries, try something like this:

```
select r.*, o.name as owner_name, p.name as reported_name
from report r
join person o on o.id = r.owner_id
join reporteduser ru on ru.report_id = r.id
join person p on p.id = ru.user_id
where r.active = true
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I should do some more testing before accepting as a right answer.